# png con transparencia se muestra con background negro

Tags: html, css, asp.net

¿Como hacer que las imagenes png no cambien el fondo de transparente a negro al momento de hacer su display desde un objeto image o image button en asp.net vb?

Comment: Deberias de agregar tu codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Pues primero verifica que tu archivo realmente tenga transparencia porque a pesar de que tenga la extensión `png` no siempre significa que si tenga transparencia, si tu archivo si tiene transparencia entonces verifica que el fondo del contenedor de donde se encuentra tu imagen, no tenga un fondo oscuro:

CSS:

```
.div-padre{
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="div-padre">
   <img src="tu_imagen.png">
</div>
```

Con eso tu imagen debería de salir normal siempre y cuando el `div` con clase `div-padre` no tenga alguna etiqueta padre que pueda afectar el color del fondo.